# Autocomplete in server or client?

Tags: c#, autocomplete, server-side, client-side

I have a winform that allows a user to input value in it's full form and in shortened form (think gmail - that allows to login with username and with username@gmail.com).
In the server, I have a method that accepts the value in it's full-form variation (username@gmail.com).
Where should the auto-complete occur; in client, or in server? Should the form convert the "username" to "username@gmail.com" and send it to server, or should the server accept both variations (in reality - a lot more variations than 2) and convert to full-form?

Winform with wcf server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Saurabh, keep it in the client, as this is not related to domain logic, and merely to simplify the user experience.

Keep your server clean :)

Answer (score 0):

is it win for web from?

i think , you should do it on the client , before sending any request to WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

Well to me, it sounds like the username is the unique key. So just send this.

If you actually do any logic with the "@something.com" then how can you only accept the username as a valid login?

Gmail will not do anything special with what you have after the @ it simply checks that is is either @googlemail.com or @gmail.com (You can log in with both or neither)

Just send what you need to the server.

Comment: Thank you, I'll place it in client.